# Removing strings from an array in c

Tags: c

I have a program that calls white, black, blue, red and yellow on string. So my question is how would I go about checking to see what strings were inputed and then printing the color that was not called.

ex. if. white, black, blue, yellow were inputed for string in my function, the program would need to printf red, this is one possibility among others such as invalid inputs such as dog, white, whale, blue, black, red, and so it should print out yellow

```
const char *string[5];
string[0] = "White";
string[1] = "Black";
string[2] = "Blue";
string[3] = "Red";
string[4] = "Yellow";

gets(string);
printf(//);
```

Comment: What do you mean here by removing ? You just wan to print last string right ?

Comment: one thing u can do is just get the index of the string u want to delete or remove lets call it index. Then move all the strings from index + 1 till end to one position up. and do size=size-1;  For printing the last string just do printf("%s",s[size-1]);

Comment: So after get S has been called 4 times or so and it checked the array for the strings provided I think I need to either keep track of which strings were called and then return the string that was not called

Comment: @Rinz1er  Here `string` and `S` are both different right ?

Comment: nope sorry for the mistake let me fix it

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You can't call `gets()` on an array of string pointers (in fact, you shouldn't use `gets()` at all, ever) and "calling" strings doesn't make any sense either. Please try to clarify what you're trying to do *in the question*, not in comments.

Comment: Simple `string[3]` would give you `red` .

Comment: you can use bit flag.

Comment: how would I use that. I know that it can clear a string but what else besides that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your declaration of the strings, and it should be `const` because we're not going to be modifying it:

```
const char *strings[] = { "white", "black", "blue", "red", "yellow" };
```

Then we can use an integer's bits to represent values in `strings` that have been input:

```
unsigned int flags = 0; /* Zero has no bits set => nothing input so far. */
```

When we get an input, we look through `strings` for a match, and set the corresponding bit in `flags`:

```
char input[1024];

if(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) != NULL)
{
  const size_t len = strlen(input);
  while(len > 0 && input[len - 1] == '\n')
    input[--len] = '\0';
  for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof strings / sizeof *strings; ++i)
  {
    if(strcmp(strings[i], input) == 0)
      flags |= 1 << i;
  }
}
```

Then finally print all `strings` that haven't been seen:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof strings / sizeof *strings; ++i)
{
  if((flags & (1 << i)) == 0)
    printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
}
```

You should be able to use pieces of the above to get what you want, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do that using enum.

define the colors you want to use

`typedef enum { WHITE = 0, BLACK, BLUE, RED, YELLOW } colors_t;`

and an array to hold strings for each defined color

```
const char * colors_str[] = {
     [ WHITE ] = "White",
     [ BLACK ] = "Black",
     [ BLUE ] = "Blue",
     [ RED ] = "Red",
     [ YELLOW ] = "Yellow"
};
```

now you can compare strings to colors like this:

```
strcmp( string_input, colors_str[ i ] )
```

and use a counter to sum all the numbers of colors that we're given as input and in the end print

```
printf( "%s", colors_str[ total - sum ] );
```

- total is the sum of all the enums ( in this example it is 10 because sum = 0+1+2+3+4 )